# Screeps getDirectionTo returning -2

Tags: javascript, direction, screeps

```
var enemy_creep = creep.pos.findNearest(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS);

if (enemy_creep) 
    var enemy_direction = creep.pos.getDirectionTo(enemy_creep);
```

I'm trying to do something like this in screeps but this function just keeps returning -2. I don't see any mention in the documentation of this error code. I've also tried the other version of the function using the x and y position of the enemy creep with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We can know the direction of a enemy but only if it's near your own creep, works fine with findInRange(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS, 1).

```
var enemy_creep = creep.pos.findInRange(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS, 1)[0];

if (enemy_creep) {
    var enemy_direction = creep.pos.getDirectionTo(enemy_creep);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `-2` is the error code for no path found, based on the [game constants](http://screeps.com/docs/Game.php#notify) (below notify) So what [ch4rlyp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185514/3163075) is saying might be correct, although the [game docs](http://screeps.com/docs/RoomPosition.php#getDirectionTo) are not saying anything about it needing to be near. Perhaps it's a bug?

> Game.ERR_NO_PATH     -2

Comment: I guess needing to be near makes sense as otherwise the direction could be one other than the 8 predefineds. I.e. if you tried to get the direction to a creep that was one square over and two up this wouldn't be a valid direction.

Comment: It would still be a valid direction, you could round to the nearest direction.